# Is a defamatory statement that could be reasonably understood as referring to someone that it does not actually refer to illegal?

Tags: united-states, defamation

From [an article on *Not the Bee*](https://notthebee.com/article/look-at-the-physics-wapo-has-to-bend-in-order-to-avoid-the-word-lies) (emphasis added):

> Joe [Biden]... lies daily, without reservation, because it has become his very way of living. To lie is to be Joe Biden. ***He takes after his father in that regard*** (let the reader understand).

On its face, this seems to be saying that Joe Biden Sr., President Biden's father, was a habitual liar, which I believe would be defamatory if Biden Sr. were still living, assuming he is not actually a habitual liar.

However, it's not actually about Biden's biological father. It's a reference to the Bible verse John 8:44:

> Ye are of your father the devil, and the lusts of your father ye will do.
> He was a murderer from the beginning, and abode not in the truth, because there
> is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh of his own: for he is a
> liar, and the father of it. (John 8:44, KJV)

Thus, the meaning is not actually "Biden lies because his human father lied," but "Biden lies because he is metaphorically a son of the devil." However, a reader not familiar with John 8:44 would likely think this was referring to Biden's human father.

If Biden's father were still living, and were not a habitual liar, would he be likely to win a defamation lawsuit against *Not the Bee* due to the possibility of confusion?

Comment: What is your rationale for presuming that the article is NOT referring to his biological father?

Comment: @MichaelHall this is a Christian conservative site that refers to the Bible often and takes a strongly negative view of President Biden, and "let the reader understand" implies that there's more to the sentence than what it directly says. The reference to a father of a liar (whether or not Biden is in fact a habitual liar is irrelevant; the author clearly believes he is) seems like a clear allusion to a verse that many, likely most, of the site's readers would be familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

The finder of fact does not have any special ability to take account of or to discover to whom a statement *actually* refers in a metaphysical sense.

#### The law

To be successful in defamation, the plaintiff must show that the published expression "would tend to lower the plaintiff's reputation in the eyes of a reasonable person" and that the published expression "**in fact referred to the plaintiff**" (*Grant v. Torstar*, [2009 SCC 61 at para. 28](https://canlii.ca/t/27430#par28)). But this is assessed from the perspective of a reasonable person and not on the basis of what the speaker *actually* meant.

When the plaintiff is not named, the question is whether there is evidence from which an "ordinary sensible person would draw the inference that the words referred to the plaintiff." That evidence must "connect the [defamation] with the plaintiff." The plaintiff needs to show that it would be reasonable for a "hypothetical sensible reader who knew the special facts" to infer that the impugned expression referred to the plaintiff and that these special facts/circumstances were known in the community. See *S.G. v. J.C.*, [2001 CanLII 3041 (Ont. C.A.) at para. 24](https://canlii.ca/t/1f8z3#par24); *Arnott v. College of Physicians and Surgeons of Saskatchewan* (1953), [[1954] 1 D.L.R. 529 (Sask. C.A.) at para. 70](https://canlii.ca/t/g79k5#par70)).

See also R.E. Brown, *The Law of Defamation in Canada*, 2nd ed. (1999), quoted in *S.G. v. J.C.* (2001), [56 O.R. (3d) 215](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onca/doc/2001/2001canlii3041/2001canlii3041.html):

> Therefore, in order to recover, the plaintiff must plead and prove that he or she is the one to whom the defamatory statement refers, that is, it must be shown to have been published 'of and concerning' the plaintiff. The defamatory publication 'must refer to some ascertained or ascertainable person, and that person must be the plaintiff.' It must refer to or concern him personally. **The test in every case is whether the ordinary sensible person to whom the words were published would understand them as referring to the plaintiff**.

Nowhere is there space in this test for the speaker to simply argue: "I didn't mean that"—it would not matter. Their argument would have to be: "a reasonable person would not understand the words to refer to Biden Sr."

#### Application

You are in as good a position as any of us to assess whether, on the facts of this situation, an ordinary sensible person would understand the words as referring to Biden Sr. I do not understand you to be simply asking for a collection of opinions from us on that issue, so I will leave the application to you.